# How can this animation be done in android

Tags: android, animation, swipe

[image: As Shown in this gif the animation of left and right swipe is needed and not the up and down swipe]

As I am beginner in android so I don't know much about the animation, I have tried to implement this using parallax ViewPager and carousal effect in view pager but both were unable to give the exact desired result.

***When the user swipes left, the view gets smaller and gets blurred and the new image along with the view gets changed. How this can be done in android.***

Do anyone have idea about how to achieve this????

Thanks for helping.

Comment: you are trying to animate with ViewPager! How many picture do you have to animate?

Comment: @EnamulHaque :- I have edited my question and have added the gif now you can see the actual animation I have to use three pages

Comment: There are about 6 or 7 different animations going on here so it's a big ask. Break them down into individual animations. Plus showing us what you have tried so far, so we have a starting point.

Comment: @billynomates :- I want to implement only two animations that are done on swipe left and swipe right

Comment: And I have tried to implement this by parallex viewpager so i am not sure whether it is done by viewpager or not

Comment: Check out https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer.html

Comment: @billynomates :- I have used the PageTransformer but the problem is that when I swipe left or right the whole page gets swiped so i can't get the desired result...... As in the GIF the first Image of leopard on the after left swipe gets aside and gets smaller and blur.And on that place a new image arrived i.e of rhinoceros